# Memory leak despite destructor call using static unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, static, unique-ptr

I use `unique_ptr` as a static data member to hold a pointer.

```
struct Test
{
    int i;
    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "destructed" << endl;
    }
};

struct S
{
    static unique_ptr<Test> te;
};
unique_ptr<Test> S::te = unique_ptr<Test>(new Test());
```

At program termination `S::te` is destructed which calls the Test-destructor.

But _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks shows me a memory leak on the memory position of `S::te.get()` which is the pointer to the (destructed) Test-object.

I don't understand this behaviour.

Can't I use a static `unique_ptr`? Why is there a leak although the destructor is called by the `unique_ptr` implementation?

Comment: Are you directly invoking `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`?

Comment: Your logic is faulty. When a tool reports that there is a memory leak in your code then that does not necessarily mean that there is a memory leak in your code. It could also be a shortcoming or bug in the leak detection tool -- or incorrect usage of said tool. In this case, your `unique_ptr` will *not* leak memory.

Comment: can you post a full working example

Comment: @jalf So, can you advise another leak detection tool for visual studio 2013 under windows which is not that faulty?

Comment: No, I didn't say the the tool is faulty necessarily. (It isn't. But you allocate memory that doesn't get freed until static objects are destroyed. And if the tool checks for leaks before then, then it will see chunks of allocated memory which have not been freed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens if you attempt to check for leaks before static destruction has occurred.

To fix this, you can call [_CrtSetDbgFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) with `_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF` at the beginning of your application; it will automatically invoke `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` at exit, after static destruction.

Comment: Only _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF shows nothing on default output but _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF) works very well, thanks.